# Using OR comparisons with IF statements

Tags: python, comparison, boolean

When using IF statements in Python, you have to do the following to make the "cascade" work correctly.

```
if job == "mechanic" or job == "tech":
        print "awesome"
elif job == "tool" or job == "rock":
        print "dolt"
```

Is there a way to make Python accept multiple values when checking for "equals to"? For example,

```
if job == "mechanic" or "tech":
    print "awesome"
elif job == "tool" or "rock":
    print "dolt"
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
if job in ("mechanic", "tech"):
    print "awesome"
elif job in ("tool", "rock"):
    print "dolt"
```

The values in parentheses are a tuple. The `in` operator checks to see whether the left hand side item occurs somewhere inside the right handle tuple.

Note that when Python searches a tuple or list using the `in` operator, it does a linear search. If you have a large number of items on the right hand side, this could be a performance bottleneck. A larger-scale way of doing this would be to use a [`frozenset`](http://docs.python.org/lib/types-set.html):

```
AwesomeJobs = frozenset(["mechanic", "tech", ... lots of others ])
def func():
    if job in AwesomeJobs:
        print "awesome"
```

The use of `frozenset` over `set` is preferred if the list of awesome jobs does not need to be changed during the operation of your program.

Comment: Since you have the accepted answer, it would be nice to also mention the `item in set()` operation for completeness.

Answer (score 4):

You can use in:

```
if job  in ["mechanic", "tech"]:
    print "awesome"
```

When checking very large numbers, it may also be worth storing off a set of the items to check, as this will be faster.  Eg.

```
AwesomeJobs = set(["mechanic", "tech", ... lots of others ])
...

def func():
    if job in AwesomeJobs:
        print "awesome"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if job in ("mechanic", "tech"):
    print "awesome"
elif job in ("tool", "rock"):
    print "dolt"
```

Answer (score 1):

While I don't think you can do what you want directly, one alternative is:

```
if job in [ "mechanic", "tech" ]:
    print "awesome"
elif job in [ "tool", "rock" ]:
    print "dolt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Tuples with constant items are stored themselves as constants in the compiled function. They can be loaded with a single instruction. Lists and sets on the other hand, are always constructed anew on each execution.

Both tuples and lists use linear search for the in-operator. Sets uses a hash-based look-up, so it will be faster for a larger number of options.

Answer (score 0):

In other languages I'd use a switch/select statement to get the job done. [You can do that in python too](http://simonwillison.net/2004/May/7/switch/).