# What is the correct way to use "or" with if condition in python

Tags: python

I have write down a code to fetch scientific literature, given code bellow fetch "xml" file and extract desired data or lines from the large file.

from this file i want two lines to be printed that contains tag "AbstractText" or "Title", when I use either "AbstractText" or  "Title" with "if" it prints desirable out put but when i used both the tags with "or" statement code starts to print all the lines.

Code which is not running correctly:

```
  def fetch_abstract(pmid):
        handle = efetch(db='pubmed', id=pmid, retmode='xml')
        lines = handle.readlines()

        for line in lines:
            if  "<AbstractText>" or "<Title>" in line:
                print line,

    fetch_abstract("19555725")
```

Code  is running correctly with  "AbstractText" tag :

```
  def fetch_abstract(pmid):
        handle = efetch(db='pubmed', id=pmid, retmode='xml')
        lines = handle.readlines()

        for line in lines:
            if  "<AbstractText>" in line:
                print line,

    fetch_abstract("19555725")
```

Code is  running correctly with "Title" tag:

```
  def fetch_abstract(pmid):
        handle = efetch(db='pubmed', id=pmid, retmode='xml')
        lines = handle.readlines()

        for line in lines:
            if   "<Title>" in line:
                print line,

    fetch_abstract("19555725")
```

how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using OR comparisons with IF statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148042/using-or-comparisons-with-if-statements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put your condition with `in line` for both:

```
if  "<AbstractText>" in line or "<Title>" in line:
```

The way you put right now has two following conditions:

```
"<AbstractText>" or
"<Title>" in line
```

and `"<AbstractText>"` is always `true` since the `string` `"<AbstractText>"` contains something (`if "nonemptystring"` is always `true`). That is why you print everything.

Answer (score 0):

One correct way is to write:

```
if "<AbstractText>" in line or "<Title>" in line:
```

Your first attempt is equivalent to `if  ("<AbstractText>") or ("<Title>" in line):`. I added the parentheses to emphasize how the line is interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if  "<AbstractText>" or "<Title>" in line:
```

use

```
if  "<AbstractText>" in line or "<Title>" in line:
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Fixed syntax error
Try this like so:

```
def fetch_abstract(pmid):
    handle = efetch(db='pubmed', id=pmid, retmode='xml')
    lines = handle.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        if  "<AbstractText>" in line or "<Title>" in line:
            print line,

fetch_abstract("19555725")
```

Comment: That's a SyntaxError.